# Sharepoint workflow association for specific list item not for entire list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using sharepoint visual studio workflow and want to associate with specific list item. workflow should only visible for that item. How can i get this done. any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. You are apparently missing the idea of workflow. Workflow definitions are not item-specific. They are supposed to represent reusable, configurable pieces of business logic that can be arbitrarily (either automatically or manually) executed for any given item (or document) in a list (library).